# Count the rows of the 'author' which is listed in the database at most

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to do the following thing:

In my MySQL table I have a column called 'Author'. The rows of this column contain the names of the authors. I would now like to find out which name is listed at most in this column and count how many times.

I am afraid that I can't provide any codes, since I don't know how to build the query yet.

Comment: `select Name, count(*) from Author group by Name order by count(*) desc Limit 1`

Comment: "I am afraid that I can't provide any codes, since I don't know how to build the query yet." That makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Author, Count(*) As CountAuthors
FROM Books
Group By Author
ORDER BY CountAuthors DESC
Limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for the SQL

```
SELECT Author, COUNT(*) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Author ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter whoops! Edited